# Pass command line args as file

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a little go tool found here: https://github.com/deusdat/gocrypttool

It takes two command line arguments: the clear text password to encrypt and the cost of the bcrypt.

If I run the command with two arguments, it works fine. When I run the command `gocrypttool "$(< example)"` where the file example exists, and holds the same two command line arguments, I get `2018/06/19 12:03:23 Please provide the password and the cost.` This error indicates that the binary didn't get arguments.

How, without adding a command line interface with prompts, can I read a file for arguments to a go binary?

Comment: @TimCooper If you want to make that comment the answer I'll take it. I see that is more of a bash issue (and operator issue). On the plus side, Google finds jack about this so you might get a good reach of help.

Comment: @TimCooper, please don't encourage unquoted expansion -- you get globbing as a result, and it's almost always unwanted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I know, this should be preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585064/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-from-a-file

Comment: The only **safe** way to store arbitrary command-line parameters in a file is in NUL-delimited form. Thus, `printf '%s\0' "$arg1" "$arg2" ... >file`, then `args=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do args+=( "$arg" ); done <file; somecommand "${args[@]}"`

Comment: @TimCooper, no, `xargs` without either `-0` or `-d` arguments isn't safe with arbitrary arguments either; by default, it tries to be shell-compatible in its parsing, but the results are subtly buggy.

Comment: @Virmundi, how are the two values in the file separated? Spaces? Are they quoted? What **exactly** is the format?

Comment: ...the above `IFS= read -r -d ''` loop is *close* to what `xargs -0 somecommand <file` does, but if your arguments are too long to fit on a command line, `xargs` will run `somecommand` more than once, whereas the loop above will fail -- which is presumably what you want, if the file contents are written to be passed to a single command invocation, splitting those arguments across multiple commands can be... well, a completely different command. (And keep in mind that maximum command-line length can vary based on the amount of space currently in use for environment variables).

Comment: Space separated. password as a string and the cost as an integer.