# How to pass the contents of a file as a parameter on the command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

Assume I want to run

```
>foo bar
```

but `bar` changes depdending on where I am in my filesystem. What I'd like to do, so I don't have to remember the proper value of `bar`, is to keep a file `fizz` in the respective folders so I can do something like call

```
>foo fizz
```

which of course doesn't work out of the box.
Neither does

```
>foo < fizz
```

because `foo` doesn't expect input, just a parameter. I found a [solution for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585064/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-from-a-file), but nothing for Windows.

Comment: As an aside: We would recommend PowerShell rather than cmd.exe shell script (batch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `fizz` contains a single line with no whitespace, the one-liner

```
for /F %i in (fizz) do @foo %i
```

will do what you want. If the argument you're putting into `fizz` may contain whitespace, use

```
 for /F "delims=" %i in (fizz) do @foo "%i"
```

to pass the argument in one piece. Double the `%` characters if putting this into a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Anton gave exactly what you wanted, and should be marked as correct answer. I can however add, (from what I have experienced before, especially in java versions) that perhaps `foo` could have a different version, similarly to how bar could differ, based on where in the file system you run it from. So `fizz` will have both executable and parameter. i.e

Content of `fizz` in path 1 :

```
foo bar
```

Content of fizz in path 2 :

```
foo1 bar2
```

then just call the content of the file, without specifying a command (as it is already present in the file `fizz`).

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (fizz) do %i
```

This method, can also run more commands in next lines that exists in `fizz` for instance if `fizz` contains:

```
ping localhost
ping 127.0.0.1
nslookup hostname1
```

Each will be ran in sequence with above for loop.

*PS!* Reminder to double up on the `%` to `%%` if you need to run it from a batch file.

Comment: If I understand your first two examples correctly, I might as well just write a folder-specific batch file that includes both the command and the parameters. While reading the first answer it occurred to me that that is actually the better solution for my specific application.

Comment: @Raketenolli almost like a batch file for each, but not quite, I will add some explanation to why it is not the same. :) Yes, like I said, the first should be marked as correct, as that is exactly like you requested and I do not expect you to mark mine as correct. Thanks for the upvote though, I do appreciate it.